# REACT APP Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

estoy en un problema que no puedo ver como salir. Voy a tratar de explicar lo mejor posible:
Tengo una app en React la cual en un componente recupera un objeto del LocalStorage, lo parsea, y mediante un bucle hace un Push de determinados elementos a un array, llamemoslo temp.
Al momento de hacer console.log a "temp" va todo perfecto, muestra que es un array con 6 elementos, cada uno un sub array de dos elementos.
Ahora bien, para que react lo renderice necesito que sea parte del estado de la app, lo cual lo hago mediante el hook useState, de esta manera:

```
    const [teamAverage, setTeamAverage] = useState([]);
```

Y luego llamo a la funcion del hook, dentro de useEffect y hago un push de cada elemento al estado teamAverage, de esta manera quedaria todo el codigo de la funcion useEffect para cambiar el estado:

```
useEffect(() =>{
let array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myTeam')); //llamado al objeto del LocalStorage
let powerStat = {};
            for(let i =0; i<array.length;i++){
            for(let key in array[i][0].powerstats){
                let sum = powerStat[key] || 0;
                powerStat[key] = sum += Number.parseInt(array[i][0].powerstats[key]);
            }
         } //recolecto los items que necesito en powerstat
let temp = [];
for(var item in powerStat){
    temp.push([item, powerStat[item]])
}
temp.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]) //ordeno los elementos del array
setTeamAverage(() => {for(let i=0; i < temp.length; i++){
    teamAverage.push(temp[i])
};
    return teamAverage})
```

En esta instancia console.log(teamAverage) me devuelve exactamente lo mismo que antes, un array con 6 sub-arrays, osea que estaria todo perfecto.
PEROO... al momento de renderizar, cuando accedo a una propiedad por ejemplo {teamAverage[0]} me sale el sub-array completo, pero si quiero acceder solo al primer indice de ese subarray (por ej teamAverage[0][0] me dice "cannot read "0" property of undefined".
No entiendo porque es undefined, si previamente el console.log me lo muestra como un array bidimensional.

Espero haberme dado a entender. Gracias por leer hasta aca, y si me pueden orientar eternamente agradecida!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres acceder a los datos primero deberias hacer una validacion que no sea undefined. algo similar a esto

```
if(teamAverage && teamAverage[i]){
 // entonces aqui recien puedes acceder a los datos
}
```

si quieres hacer la validacion en el codigo html entonces debes usar las condiciones dentro de un bloque {}

```
{teamAverage &&<YourComponent/>

}
```

Comment: Entiendo. En mi caso, como puse abajo, por ejemplo quisiera acceder a esa info directamente en una etiqueta de encabezado o un párrafo, pondría la etiqueta dentro del bloque de ese If? Gracias!

Comment: @amoqs he editado mi respuesta

Comment: Mil gracias! Ha funcionado al momento de renderizar la info del array colocando la validacion con &&, pongo el ejemplo de como quedo una etiqueta final al renderizar por si a alguien mas le sirve: <h1> Bienvenido {teamAverage[5] && teamAverage[5][0]</h1>. Con esa validacion pude acceder a propiedades mas profundas sin el horrendo error de UNDEFINED. jaja mil gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El useEffect tiene un ciclo de vida de manera que se va a ejecutar después de renderizar el DOM, por tanto, no estás respetando el ciclo de vida.
Como dicen arriba comprueba primero y cuando se haya cargado todo... entonces se renderizará correctamente.

```js
return { teamAverage[0] && teamAverage[0][0] || 'valor por defecto' }
```

Comment: Entiendo, entonces el undefined es porque intento acceder a la variable antes que el programa renderice y le declare la info. Te hago una pregunta más, yo accedo a la variable en el código que regresa el componente para generar por ejemplo un encabezado h1 con ese título. Por ejemplo: <h1>{teamAverage[0][1]}</h1> , funcionaria esa comprobación condicional se esa manera? Mil gracias!!! Ya me queda mucho más claro

Comment: @amoqs efectivamente. Si quieres poner en el h1 eso, con que compruebes que existe primero el {teamAverage[0]} serviría. De hecho es lo mismo que hacer una comprobación con un if primero. 
Es lo mismo 

`if (teamAverage[0]) {
 teamAverage[0][1];
}`
que poner un 
`{ teamAverage[0] && teamAverage[0][1] }`

Answer (score 1):

Podes utilizar el operador optional chaning ?. para validar si existe el dato.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

seguido de un find.
El cual busca el primer valor valido de un arreglo.
Si existe un dato, entonces te va a retornar su valor, caso contrario
te va a retornar como undefined.

Aca te dejo un ejemplo:
Intento recorrer un arreglo que solo tiene 3 posiciones, en un for que va de 0 a  10.

```js
const myArray=[
[{powerstats:"value"}],
[{powerstats:"value2"}],
[{powerstats:"value3"}],

]

for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
  value=myArray[i]?.find(i=>i);
  console.log(value)
}
```

Podemos ver que el codigo no explota.
Podes hacer lo mismo para tu codigo, haciendo una validacion de que exista el dato, antes de ejecutar tu for.

```js
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      //Es importante siempre poner el operador ?. antes de acceder a un atributo de un objecto.
      //con esto nos aseguramos de validar que exista el valor.
      //Si no ingresamos el operador y el atributo no existe, entonces el codigo explotara.
      //Es una buena practica agregarlo.

      const powerStats = array[i]?.find(i=>i)?.powerstats;
      //Si no existe el dato entonces no ejecuto el resto del codigo.
      if(!powerStats){
          return ;
      }

      for (let key in powerStats) {
        let sum = powerStat[key] || 0;
        powerStat[key] = sum += Number.parseInt(array[i][0].powerstats[key]);
      }
}
```